# Can I bring this drain system up to code?

Tags: plumbing, drain, code-compliance

I'm redoing a bathroom upstairs and a living space directly below it. I'd love to replace the cast iron & galvanized steel drain pipes with PVC while I'm here (also plan to replace the water lines with pex). I tore out the ceiling today and I can't imagine this 4-way joint would be up to code.

[image: Labeled picture of plumbing in ceiling]

The bathroom on the left is fairly modern so hope to avoid tearing it up, but it seems much more problematic. The bathroom on the right seems fine to me. Would love any advice. The wall between the 2 bathrooms is roughly straight above the length of copper pipe.

[image: A different angle of the plumbing]

[image: Location of the toilet flange]

Comment: A) What is it that you don't think is to code? B) If it was to code when it was installed, it is "grandfathered" in now unless you start changing it. C) My understanding is that cast iron will be _far_ quieter when that toilet flushes than any more modern material would be. Removing the cast iron would actually be a downgrade.

Comment: Just taking a SWAG bit I do not see any venting, is there one in the bathroom on the left, if not that would explain why it is problematic.

Comment: Would leave the pipes as they are,unless you are thinking of increasing the diameter of the copper, then you have to do all the pipes in the house.  Cast and copper probably last longer than the house.  If it is not broken, don't fix.

Comment: @FreeMan, thanks so much for editing the pictures inline!  I am fairly sure the cross pipe is not to code, from what I can find horizontal to horizontal transitions must be very gradual - long sweeps or 45 wyes.

Comment: @Gil I am concerned about the venting.  There is one vent coming in to that 4x2 cross on the right - it is a wet vent sharing the drain with a tub and sink.  Not sure if that is up to code either.

Comment: It is true that cast pipe is quieter than pvc, but cast (especially when ran horizontally) is well known to corrode and rust.  They are not as smooth as PVC and are more prone to clogs as well.  These pipes are from the 60s and really showing their age.

Comment: I cannot really say if it is up to code as I do not know what part of the world you are from nor your local codes. You should talk to your local plumbing inspector and determine what they have to say. In the end they are the ones approving it. That is probably not what you wanted to here but is the best answer I can give you.

Comment: Please revise your post to ask something more specific. It's not clear what problem you're trying to solve (hence all the comments and no answers).

Comment: @Brad the horizontal double sanitary tee wouldn't be up to UPC code today, but there's no requirement to retrofit old plumbing to conform to current code unless you modify that plumbing in any way (or in some cases if you are selling the property).